# Peer-to-peer Windows 7 file sharing "access denied" to one user on XP client

Tags: windows, permissions, file-sharing, peer-to-peer

In a peer-to-peer network where Windows 7 is sharing a folder with particular users only (not 'Everyone') the Windows XP client receives "Access denied" message when one user attempts to access resource. A second user set up on client and server is able to access resource with no problem. Usernames and passwords are the same on both computers and they are not in a domain.

I have found two workarounds:

1. Add 'Everyone' to file sharing permissions
2. On the XP client, add a stored network password under User Accounts/Manage network passwords in the form "server\username".

Not sure why this behavior changed but would like to be able to access the shared resource without the extra step of specifying the password in Stored User Names and Passwords.

Comment: So, do you have *several* user accounts, which are given permission to access the share (i.e. each computer is using its own account to access the share), or do you use *one* account (with all computers using this account to access the share)

Comment: There are two accounts; the non-administrator account is the account most users are using from multiple computers. This is the account that is working. The account that is not working is the admin account and it is only being used from one computer.

Comment: I verified that the network type is set to 'Work' and enabled an option called "Password protected sharing". Now when the non-working user attempts to connect it prompts for a password; if I choose to remember it it is saved to Stored User Names and Passwords.

This is better but I would like to figure out why it isn't working automatically given that the username and password is the same.

Comment: You need to enable 40/56 bit encryption on W7.  WXP cannot handle 128bit encryption.

Answer (score 0):

You could attempt to make the change *permanent* by using the following command:

`NET USE [x:] \\<SERVER>\<SHARE> <PASSWORD> /USER:<SERVER\USERNAME> /PERSISTENT:YES`

Replace any values enclosed in greater and less than signs (< and >) with the correct values.

I said *permanent* because, at times, the user might lose the drive connection. Just repeat the steps if that happens. The `[x:]` part is optional, but if you put an unused drive letter in there, you will map a drive letter to the share, if that's preferred.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, but this only seems to work until the computer is restarted.

Comment: Even with the `/PERSISTENT:YES` entry? Weird. Does the computer affected have `File and Printer Sharing` enabled in the network adapter properties of the device you're using?

Comment: Yes, I can switch users and it will work just fine. I can also access the share when permission for 'Everyone' is enabled.